# Database of evacuation sites in Japan (places to take refuge after a natural disaster)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, japan, geohazard

Japan has thousands of "evacuation sites" that people should flee to in case of disaster, in particular if their house is burning, or about to collapse.

Is there a database of the latitude/longitude of all of them?
I would like to make an app pointing to the closest one.

They are known under different names, because there are various types of them, and various municipalities might use different names:

- 一時滞在施設 ("temporary meeting place")
- 避難場所 ("evacuation site")
- 避難所 ("shelter")

The data for Tokyo can easily be scraped from http://map.bousai.metro.tokyo.jp but rather than scraping Japan's 1719 municipalities one by one, I would prefer a data set that already contains them all. Or at least by prefecture (Japan has 47 prefectures).

Comment: This is a worldbank document that discusses data collection on evacuation centers in Japan. Perhaps you might find references to what you are looking for in the doc. - https://www.google.com/#q=japan+evacuation+center+dataset

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode: You gave a Google URL. Did you mean the 5th result [Hazard and Risk Information and Decision Making](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/16145/800710drm0kn5020Box0377295B00PUBLIC0.txt?sequence=2)?

Comment: Oops, here is the correct link: https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/16145/800710drm0kn5020Box0377295B00PUBLIC0.txt?sequence=2

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Japan collected 45,000 these entries at https://loco.yahoo.co.jp/search/?genrecd=0425 . There are also buttons to display them on map and such.

Example entry: https://loco.yahoo.co.jp/place/g-WsTnclfhKys/?genrecd=0425

Edit: Information can be accessed via API, information about the Yahoo Loco service api: https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/map/openlocalplatform/v1/localsearch.html
The "genre code" for these evacuation sites in Yahoo Loco is 0425.

Comment: So the idea would be to scrape from the Yahoo website? Is it allowed by their terms of use?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Updated the answer to include link to Yahoo Loco's api intro page

Comment: I don't see any API call to download the whole database, so I guess I would have to send many local requests to scrape everything?